# puppet variables

Tags: puppet

I am trying to use variables in my modules manifest.pp with little luck

```
class mysoftware($version="dev-2011.02.04b") {
  File {
    links => follow
  }

  file { "/opt/mysoftware":
    ensure => directory
  }
  file { "/opt/mysoftware/share":
    source => "puppet://puppet/mysoftware/air/$version",
    recurse => "true",
  }
  }
```

This does not seem to be working when I assign this to a node via the nodes.pp file.

I am running puppetmaster 2.6.4
puppetd clients are 0.25

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you need to reference it like this:

```
source => "puppet://puppet/mysoftware/air/${version}",
```

Here's how I use something similar:

```
class aliases($al="aliases") {
    file { "/etc/aliases":
        mode  => 640,
        source => "puppet:///files/sendmail/${al}",
        owner => "root",
        group => "root",
        before  => Exec["create aliases db"]
    }

     exec { "new_aliases":
        command => "/usr/bin/newaliases",
        subscribe => File["/etc/aliases"],
        alias => "create aliases db",
        refreshonly => true,
     }
}
```

Which I reference from manifests/nodes.pp.  I actually don't need to do it that way but set it up and tested it on your behalf (my other examples would have been much longer).  Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using 2.6 or older? Parameterized classes are new in 2.6, so if you're using an older version, this should not work.

Comment: I am using 2.6.4 puppetmaster with 0.25 puppet clients.

Comment: Then I can only answer the question if it should work with a _maybe_. The puppetmaster compiles the client's catalog, which I would guess is where the feature would need to exist, but it seems like treading on thin ice.

Comment: Ok, I cannot figure out how to get a newline in the previous post to make a new paragraph, so I'll continue here... I would start by testing on the puppetmaster itself using the stand-alone interpreter (what prior to 2.6 was called just 'puppet', whereas the puppetmaster-client was called 'puppetd') doing something trivial, like copying /etc/hosts to /tmp or running /bin/echo. Once you get that to work, try to add it to a node and see if it works there too. If so, then you have a simple but working example and you can compare that with the one that isn't working.

Comment: I think the easiest thing would be to upgrade my puppet clients to a new version. Is it possible to update puppet client versions with a module?

Comment: If you're using a Linux system with something like yum or apt-get or one of the similar tools that most other distros have, or Solaris with the Blastwave/OpenCSW with the pkg-get tool _and_ are installing Puppet from one of them, then it should be pretty easy--just use a `package` resource and set the `ensure` attribute to either the version you want installed or _latest_.

Comment: @joey - You don't need to update you puppet clients for this to work since it's server side (although updating the clients isn't a bad idea).